# Sorting points by distance on Amazon RDS with Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, amazon-rds, geodjango

Quick background, I'm trying to create a django app that sorts a bunch of locations by distance from a point.  The app will be running on an EC2 server, and I would like to use RDS for the database.  Because PostgreSQL is not available on RDS I chose to use MySQL.

**The Problem:**

When I try to run the view, I get the error:

> NotImplementedError: distance stored procedure not available on the mysql backend.

Here is the view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from models import CampSite
from geopy import geocoders
from django.contrib.gis.geos import *
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
from django.template import RequestContext

def results(request):
     query = request.GET['q']
     g = geocoders.Google(resource='maps')
     results = []
     geocodes = g.geocode(query, exactly_one=False)
     for geocode in geocodes:
         location, (lat, lon) = geocode
         pnt = fromstr("POINT(%s %s)" % (lon, lat))
         distance_from_point = {'mi':'2000'}
         results.append(CampSite.objects.filter(
            lonlat__distance_lte=(
                    pnt,
                    D(**distance_from_point)
                    )
            ).distance(pnt).order_by('distance')
         )
       return render_to_response('results.html',{'location': location,
             'lat': lat, 'lon': lon, 'results':results[0]},
             context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

From what I've read, I think the problem is that MySQL isn't OGC Compliant and that using GDAL to get the information could work, but I have no idea how to implement that.

Does anyone know how I could get the app to work using RDSpreferably with MySQL? ( I would like to avoid Heroku)

p.s. I am using geopy to make the request to Google.

Comment: Maybe setup an postgresql db with postgis on that server. MySql is a really poor choice here.

Comment: Yea, I would prefer to use RDS for ease in scaling.  It looks like the only other RDS option is oracle or microsoft SQL server.

Comment: Since you have lat and lon, does this approach work for you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/593/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-locations-using-stored-procedure-in-mysql

Comment: Mongodb also has some geo support, and hosted services. It is however somewhat harder to use with django, although there is this django-norel.

Answer (score 0):

Funny to think about it but at the time you asked this question, MySQL version 5.6 wasn't available and therefore there was no support for distance queries. This version became available some days after your question [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL#Milestones).

Since then some things have changed:

1. MySQL has and supports spatial datatypes and queries. It still does not comply with OGC standards though.
2. Amazon RDS now [supports PostgreSQL](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/).

My personal preference for a spatial database is PostgreSQL with PostGIS and I would recommend its use.

Finally, assuming that your `CampSite` model has a field of type `Point` named 'pnt' and you want to make a query to return the Camp Sites ordered by distance from a reference point (named: `ref_pnt`), you can fo it with the following query:

```
CampSites.objects.annotate(dist=Distance('pnt', ref_pnt)).orderby('dist')
```